# destroying top level window in Tkinter takes a lot of time

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am new to Tkinter, I created a top-level window and embedded many figures (using matplotlib) in the top-level window. If I use destroy() to close the top-level window, it takes a lot of time to close the top-level window, it destroys every figure in the top-level window and then destroys the top-level window. If use quit(), it faster but it closes all my program while I just want to close the top-level window. I want to know is there any way to speed up closing the top-level window

Comment: Try calling `<tkinter.Toplevel>.withdraw()` first. That will hide the window so the user shouldn't be able to notice the delay when you call `<tkinter.Toplevel>.destroy()`. Also please give us some minimal working code, so we can test our solutions.

Comment: @TheLizzard , Thank you, I have tried using withdraw(), but I can't do anything on the main window until the top-level window is really destroyed. I have also tried using thread, but it does not seem to work well when I have more figures, my program is even interrupted. Here is my code: https://github.com/p-x-quyen/tmp/blob/main/plot_gui.py

Comment: I looked at your code and it seems that destroying all of the `FigureCanvasTkAgg` objects takes a lot of time. Add the `matplotlib` tag to your question and try finding a way of combining all of the plots into 1 `FigureCanvasTkAgg`. I don't know much about how `FigureCanvasTkAgg` works.

Comment: ok, I will try, thank you very much